# NSIS - how to stop it from creating a directory?

Tags: nsis

Upon uninstalling, I go through a list of installed subdirectories (List - C#)and delete them. I check if a directory exists and if so, I want to remove it. Here's the code:

```
 //here it deletes the testfolder1 directory - perfect
 ${If} ${FileExists} "$MUSIC\testFolder1\*"
 RMDir "$MUSIC\testFolder1"
 ${EndIf}

 //problem - here, instead of ONLY CHECKING if directory exists,
 // it creates "testFolder1" again!
 ${If} ${FileExists} "$MUSIC\testFolder1\testfolder2\*"
 RMDir "$MUSIC\testFolder1\testfolder2"
 ${EndIf}
```

I know I could swap the two ifs and it would work but it doesn't solve anything, because directories are in a random order in my list. Is there any way to stop NSIS from creating directories upon checking if they exist? I have looked for a solution online but found absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how that is possible, `${IfFileExists}` is a wrapper around `IfFileExists` and internally this NSIS instruction is implemented with [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx). There is not way this is going to create a directory!

The upside is that you don't have to use `${IfFileExists}` because `RMDir` (without `/r`) will only delete the directory if it is empty and does nothing if it does not exist.

If you don't know the order of the directories nor if they can be nested at compile-time then you must keep trying to delete as long as you succeeded to delete at least one item:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
CreateDirectory "$Temp\testFolder1"
CreateDirectory "$Temp\testFolder1\testfolder2"

!macro TryRMDir path counter
ClearErrors
${IfThen} ${FileExists} "${path}" ${|} IntOp ${counter} ${counter} + 1 ${|}
RMDir "${path}" 
${IfThen} ${FileExists} "${path}" ${|} IntOp ${counter} ${counter} - 1 ${|}
!macroend
loop:
    StrCpy $0 0
    !insertmacro TryRMDir "$Temp\testFolder1" $0
    !insertmacro TryRMDir "$Temp\testFolder1\testfolder2" $0
StrCmp $0 0 "" loop ; If we deleted anything we must try again
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, it has worked. Trust me, my initial approach DOES create a folder - it is possible! I've just tested it again. If you first of all delete testfolder1 and second of all testfolder1\testfolder2 the testfolder1 STAYS there (gets created). If you swap the commands, both get deleted! You can try it out for yourself if you want.

Comment: I'm telling you it is not possible. Don't use Explorer to check because it cannot be trusted.